# Using two projects with different configuration settings in a single solution visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, matlab, visual-studio-2012

I am using a a single solution to reside two projects in visual studio 2012.

**Project 1:**

- wpf
- uses "any cpu" configurations (which is a must)

**Project 1:**

- winforms
- uses "x86" configurations (which is a must again)

the solution runs like this.

the window from wpf application opens up as startup window. from here a button is pressed to open a form in winform project.

Problem: if i keep the configuration as any cpu, the winform window wont open up and give an error. If i keep the configuration as x86 the wpf would give an error becasue the mlapp (matlab application) i am using wont be recognised.

please help.

Comment: you have no choice, you must go down to x86 for WPF. your winform project will only run x86 and be emulated on x64 !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set individual projects to respective configurations as per requirement and then setting the overall solution configuration to "mixed platforms". it worked